# How to get all remote computer's usernames via Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there any way to get list of all local user accounts on a remote computer via Powershell?

Comment: Do you mean local user accounts or the users currently logged in?

Comment: yes, all users that stored in SAM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get this with a WMI-query.

```
function Get-LocalUser ($Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
    Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_UserAccount Where LocalAccount = 'True'" -ComputerName $ComputerName |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
}

Get-LocalUser -ComputerName "TestPC1"
```